# How would an extremely thigmotropic plant store enough energy?

Tags: biology, flora, preservation

Clingy Vine eats animals when they come in contact with it by rapidly growing over them and killing them - a bit like a strangler fig.
The main problem I’m running into is that it would need loads of energy to grow and cover the animal.
How would it have enough energy on standby to rapidly grow enough to touch it and consume the unfortunate animal?

Thigmotropism is the reaction to touch.

Comment: What is a "thigmotropic"?

Comment: @Daron, thigmotropism is the response to touch. Wouldn’t an organism with thigmotrophic responses be using thigmotropism?

Comment: You should add that to the question body.

Comment: Even if you have unlimited energy, you'd need some wildly different biology to grow that fast. The fastest-multiplying, simplest bacterial cells take tens of minutes to double, and more complex eukaryotic cells which make up plants take hours if not days. A solution that doesn't involve actual new growth might be more plausible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Starch = Potato Anchor

Plants store their excess energy in the form of starch. That starch, depending on the plant in questions, can be directed to a few different places. I think the most useful application here for your needs would be potatoes. Potato plants keep relatively large stores of their starchy fuel in the root (like any root vegetable, really) and the more extra resources the plant has access to, the larger the store.

For us humans, that tends to mean bigger potatoes. For your plants, that could mean more capability to respond and entrap prey. Imagine, if you will, your vine appears to be relatively small on the surface, but underneath it rests a massive starch container that may, or may not, look like a 2-foot-tall potato. From this store, the plant draws all the energy it could need to respond to and wrap around the target.

There are believability issues with the ability of the plant to transport the starch in a timely fashion, but there are a few ways to address this.  There are a couple of approaches you have for applying this tactic. You could just make your plants very aggressive and capable of actual quick growth, wherein they suddenly grow to many times their length, wrap around prey, and hold it to the ground. The starch store would act as a heavy anchor holding the plant, and its prisoner, firmly to the ground.

The other approach is a bit sneakier, slower, and more believable. The key is preparation, foreshadowing, and suspense. The vines are already quite tall, thin, and spread out, appearing as if they are different, individual, weak plants. The would-be explorer is moving throw the area, and they swear they saw a plan move as they walked by it, but decide that’s crazy. They sit down to rest, and accidentally fall asleep.

The nearby clingy vine’s proximity sense triggers, and it’s tall, thin vines slowly begin to wrap around the sleeping adventurer. This require less energy overall, as the vines are falling to the ground. As they wrap around, they form a thick interwoven netting of vines that would be weak by themselves but together are very strong. The ends of the wines wrap around and cling to whatever they can: skin, clothes, digging into the ground. The effect is thousands of tiny frictional points that create a full coverage of resistance.

When the unsuspecting traveler wakes, they are wrapped up completely and cannot move. The plant’s remaining stores anchor it down, and at this point someone either comes to cut free our hero, or they never escape and slowly die of thirst or exposure. This is how the plant replenishes its massive stores. The trapped and dead act as decay material, feeding the soil with nutrients each time it captures one. It’s a high-risk, high-reward scenario with, if a plant is unable to retain its catch that it spends all this energy on, it will likely die.

Comment: I think I’ll use both approaches as different plants. There’s no such thing as two many dangerous plants, are there…

Answer (score 2):

**Nastic movement**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nastic_movements

> Nastic movements are non-directional responses to stimuli (e.g.
> temperature, humidity, light irradiance), and are usually associated
> with plants. The movement can be due to changes in turgor.

Your plant has already grown all its thorny vines.  They lay in a flaccid heap on the ground.  But when prey stumbles in, they get nastic!  These vines are erectile tissue and they spring up turgidly around the prey animal.

This is not growth per se though the vine did grow all tissues involved, over time and in the normal way.  The vine has a large contractile organ underground full of water (and toxins and digestive juices).  The mighty contraction of that organ causes a surge of fluids into the thorny vines which cause them to rise up, penetrating the animal and injecting their fluids.

The animals do not struggle long but struggles may tear the vines.  The vines are valved and so a tear in one place does not deplete pressure for the whole.  Once the animal has been subdued the vines then use normal growth, extending roots down through the thorns to absorb the nutrients of the prey.   The contraction bladder can recharge over time to prepare for the next deployment.